# Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The error says that there is an: "undefined method []"
My questions is simply how to solve the error

My user.rb file where the error says the error is and where i think the error is

```
def your_questions(params)
    questions.paginate(page: params[:page], order: 'created_at DESC', per_page: 3)
end
```

My questions controller a.k.a app/controllers/questions_controller.rb

```
    class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :auth, only: [:create, :your_questions, :edit, :update]

  # def index
  #     @question = Question.new
  #   @questions = Question.unsolved(params)
  # end

  def self.unsolved(params)
    order('created_at DESC').where(solved: false).paginate(page: params[:page],per_page: 3)
  end

  def create
    @question = current_user.questions.build(params[:question])
    if @question.save
        flash[:success] = 'Your question has been posted!'
        redirect_to @question
    else
      @questions = Question.unsolved(params)
        render 'index'
    end
  end

  def new
       @question = Question.new
  end

  def show
    # raise FOO
    puts params
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answer = Answer.new
  end

  def your_questions
    @questions = current_user.your_questions(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @question = current_user.questions.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @question = current_user.questions.find(params[:id])

    if @question.update_attributes(params[:question])
      flash[:success] = 'Your question has been updated!'
      redirect_to @question
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def search
    @questions = Question.search(params)
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You pass `params[:id]` into `your_questions` method, while it expects `params`. What I'd do is:

```
def your_questions(page)
  questions.paginate(page: page, order: 'created_at DESC', per_page: 3)
end
```

It's because this method doesn't need to know about your whole `params` hash. Then you call this method simply with `params[:page]`:

```
current_user.your_questions(params[:page])
```

Comment: So where should I put that code, in my questions controller?

Comment: @user00000001 No, `your_questions` should remain in `User` model.

Comment: where should i put this? current_user.your_questions(params[:page])

Comment: @user00000001 in controller, replacing similar piece of code in `your_questions` action.

Answer (score 0):

Your are passing only `id` when you have called `your_questions` in your controller. However you are trying to fetch a key `:page` from `id (string)`

Just Do following change in your controller's `your_questions`

```
@questions = current_user.your_questions(params[:page])
```

In your `user.rb` just use `page` instead of `params[:page]`

```
def your_questions(page)
    questions.paginate(page: page, order: 'created_at DESC', per_page: 3)
end
```

Comment: when i put this code in it says: "undefined local variable or method `current_user' for QuestionsController:Class"

Comment: @user00000001 nothing changed with `current_user` in above mentioned answer. This is just about passing correct parameter to the method. It must be some other issue